# Implement a "Likes system" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to figure out how to setup the following. A user can create a review and then like his review or like other reviews if he wants to. I came up with the following setup:

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :review
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :likes
  has_many :liked_reviews, through: :likes, source: :review
end

class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes
  has_many :liking_users, :through => :likes, :source => :user
end 

class CreateLikes < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :likes do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :likes, index: true
      t.integer :review_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I'm pretty sure that the model associations I came up with are correct, but I'm not so sure about the like table. Can someone please review the above and tell me if the model associations and like table are correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's with the "t.references :likes, index: true" in your table definition? also you might want to look into the AR counter cache feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Nick M. Not sure why i put `t.references :likes, index: true` in there. Maybe I should remove it and only have this in the likes migration: `t.references :user, index: true t.integer :review_id`...what do think is that correct?

Comment: Maybe you can use t.references :review

Comment: I was about to say that. Maybe I should change the entire likes migration table to have only this: `t.references :user, index: true, t.references :review, index: true`  is this what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes that should do it, try running it and see how it goes. Also definitely add a counter cache on reviews for likes since you'll probably be doing a lot of Review.likes.count in your pages.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the header up! Can you provide any links for the `counter cache` feature?

Comment: I've done it using polymorphism. The Like belongs to an owner and a target. Then the user has_many likes as owner and the review has many likes as target.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Int'l Man Of Coding Mystery. So just to get this right... `like class: belongs_to: owner, belongs_to :target` and the `review class: has_many :likes as: :owner, has_many :likes as: :target` ??? and what about the like table migration... how will that look?

Comment: `create_table :likes do |t| t.references :owner, polymorphic: true t.references :target, polymorphic: true t.timestamps`

Comment: I made a gem, WIP, but supposed to do these things for you :D Here's the migration for likes that I have. https://github.com/mikeyduece/soc_med/blob/master/db/migrate/20200605151411_create_soc_med_likes.rb

Comment: Thanks for the help!!! I'll take a look at the gem and maybe use it

Comment: Something I'd add a validation to avoid replicated likes, so a user can only like a review once